# how to get the number of inotify watches in use

Tags: linux, inotify

I use `inotifywait` for event trigger which put file.

When many files are watched by `inotifywait`, when `max_user_watches` is exceeded, the following error occurs.

> Terminating since out of inotify watches.#012Consider increasing /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

It is necessary to tune `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`, but is it possible to check the current file watch number?

Is there a way to check like *file-nr* in file descriptor?

Comment: I had the same question -- I found this before I saw this answer: https://github.com/mikesart/inotify-info

Answer (score 30):

I cobbled together [this little script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) based on @mosvy's answer. Since the initial conception, it has since seen quite a few improvements (stability on older systems, total count, speed). On most *normal* machines, running it should take a less than 100 ms.

```
   INOTIFY
    WATCH
    COUNT     PID USER     COMMAND
--------------------------------------
    3044   3933 myuser node /usr/local/bin/tsserver
    2965   3941 myuser /usr/local/bin/node /home/myuser/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-tsserver/bin/tsserverForkStart /hom
     979   3954 myuser /usr/local/bin/node /home/myuser/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-tsserver/node_modules/typescript/li
       1   3899 myuser /usr/local/bin/node --no-warnings /home/myuser/dev/dotfiles/common-setup/vim/dotvim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/i

    6989  WATCHES TOTAL COUNT
```

---

**2023 Update: use a native version**

Michael Sartain has recreated this functionality (and added several  improvements) as a native (C++) binary ([inotify-info](https://github.com/mikesart/inotify-info)), so if you can spare a few seconds to do the build step, his project essentially makes my script redundant, as it is better in every way. Superfast!

---

Comment: How about the total number?

Comment: Which total number? The total number of watchers? Just change the script to sum the counts.

Comment: Got a PR in that added the total number! https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/pull/3

Comment: Used this script third time, so adding this for future convenience:


`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fatso83/dotfiles/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers | sh`

Answer (score 11):

I wish I was able to answer with something smarter, but the only way I found to count the `inotify(7)` watches set by a user is this:

```
find /proc/*/fd -user "$USER" -lname anon_inode:inotify \
   -printf '%hinfo/%f\n' 2>/dev/null |
   xargs cat | grep -c '^inotify'
```

Change `"$USER"` with the actual user you want info about;  `` "`id -u`" `` for the current user. Notice that the `max_user_watches` is a per-user limit, not per process, or per inotify instance / file descriptor.

This will first `find` all open file descriptors created by `inotify_init*(2)`, and will then look into the corresponding `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD` file for the info about the watch descriptors added with `inotify_add_watch(2)` to each of them (look into the [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manpage under `/proc/[pid]/fdinfo/` for a description of the inotify-specific entries). The `-c` option of `grep` will let it print a count of all lines that match a pattern.

**Note:** the counter for `inotify_watches` is kept just like other per-user counters in a `struct ucounts` referenced from the user namespace structure -- see [`include/linux/user_namespace.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/user_namespace.h?id=2137397c92aec3713fa10be3c9b830f9a1674e60#n77); but I wasn't able to find any interface exposing those counters to userland.

Comment: By the way, thanks for posting this answer. I wrapped the concept (a bit modified) into a script that became quite useful for a lot of folks. Sharing is caring :)