# What is this `gmain` process with these unknown PIDs in my trace file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inotify, tracing

Reading up on an [answer to find out which process registered inotify watchers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62284/18594), I executed the following commands

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_exit_inotify_add_watch/enable
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
```

The resulting output from the `trace` file had a header that indicated that the first column should have the name of the process (task?), along with the PID:

```
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
           gmain-1715  [004] .... 23200.386116: sys_inotify_add_watch -> 0xfffffffffffffffe
```

Surprisingly, none of the PIDs listed in the many lines of output exist when I grep for them using `ps -ef | grep $THE_PID` (where $THE_PID would be 1715). Also, the task name is unknown to me and does not exist in the `ps` output either.

Further, the *entire* list is all tuples like `gmain-<some number>`. Not the expected `postgres` or `node`. So what *is* this `gmain` process? And what are these PIDs that do not exist in /proc/? Are they historic by the time I try accessing them?

I see `gmain` is a thing [in these kernel docs by Theodore Ts'o on tracing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/events.txt), so it's *something*.

Comment: this is not answering your actual question, but the original problem: that answer you link to is not the best approach; info about watches set by inotify is present since linux 3.8 in `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD`, so you can adapt my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501952/308316) to a similar question: `find /proc/*/fd -lname anon_inode:inotify    -printf '%hinfo/%f\n' 2>/dev
/null | xargs grep -c '^inotify'`. There are better answers (using fdinfo) even to the question you're linking to.

Comment: Ooh, nice oneliner! I even learned a new thing with the `-c` option. Genius.

Comment: @mosvy I cobbled togheter this utility script from your comment: https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These are not processes.  These are *tasks*.  Linux works in terms of tasks.  You do not see their IDs in a *process* list because *these* tasks happen to be threads within a process.  They are the worker threads of some multi-threaded [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/) process somewhere.  You'll find them in the `task/` subdirectory of the `/proc/<process>` subdirectory (example `/proc/860/task/926`).

Comment: You posted _just_ as I did :-) Didn't know about the `task` directory though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, this `gmain` process had something to do with GTK or Gnome, but the thing to note is that it wasn't a *process* at all, but a *thread* (the gtk main loop)! That's also why it didn't show when grepping `ps`.

I understood this when using the `-q` option to `ps`, which lets you list the pids you are interested in. The pid that came up wasn't the one I passed as an option at all, but still showed when I did `pstree -p`, which made me think this was perhaps some kind of thread.

Using my newfound knowledge, I found that I could list all the threads, that also have PIDs (is this the right name?) of their own by supplying `ps` with the `-L` option.

Example: `sudo ps -efL -q  906`.

This (and `pstree`) led me to find out that the thread belonged to `NetworkManager`).